# is there an addon or another way to record the camera movement with middle mouse?

Tags: animation, camera

So basically I just rotate camera with mouse and I want to bake that somehow into animation instead of manual positioning. WOuld be handy thing

Comment: (1) Enable auto-keyframing. (2) Go into camera view. (3) enable "Lock camera to view". (4) Play the animation and navigate the view while looking through the camera. For the movements, key will be recorded on the play-backed frames.

Comment: Awesome! Much appreciate! Just one question, can I see recorded keyframes so I could edit them if needed? Because I see only one (on the 1-st frame)

Comment: Yes, they will be on the camera, accessible through the timeline or dopesheet or graph editor.